# How to make a ShareIt like animation in Android for searching nearby Bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I'm working on a simple Android Bluetooth app that will search for nearby bluetooth devices and connect to them. Currently, I'm displaying all the nearby Bluetooth devices in a `ListView`, but I want to achieve something like the following:

[image: This is used to ShareIt app]

**More importantly,** I want to show an appropriate icon here for every nearby Bluetooth device. For example, if it's a phone, then icon should be of a phone, if a Bluetooth Audio device, then a headphone icon.

How can this be done?

Thank for your time!

Comment: Hi, did you found the solution how it can be done? if yes can you share the reference or working example or anything related to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out,

https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid

Put this in a relative layout and your icons too, when user taps on them, take them to the next activity!